# Why does this 'else if' statement not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

JavaScript won't work unless I delete the `else if` statement. Once I do, everything works perfectly fine, but I really need that change that can be done with `else if`. Can't figure out why. What it does is changes the menu state over a certain section with top and bottom defined, not only top of my page.

```
//MENU COLOR CHANGE

$(document).ready(function() {
    var a = $(".nav-mobile");
    var b = $(".brand-box");
    var c = $(".menu_item");
    var d = $(".facebook-top");
    var e = $(".vk-top");
    var f = $(".menu-item-facebook");
    var g = $(".menu-item-vk");
    var h = $(".head-block");
    var posup = b.position();
    var posdown = h.position();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (windowpos <= posup.top) {
            a.removeClass("nav-mobile-black");
            c.removeClass("menu-item-black");
            d.removeClass("facebook-top-black");
            e.removeClass("vk-top-black");
            f.removeClass("menu-item-facebook-black");
            g.removeClass("menu-item-vk-black");

            $(".menu_item").mouseover(function(){
            $(this).css({"background-color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)"});
            });
            $(".menu_item").mouseout(function(){
            $(this).css({"background-color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)"});
            });  
        } 
      else if (windowpos >= posdown.top) {
            a.removeClass("nav-mobile-black");
            c.removeClass("menu-item-black");
            d.removeClass("facebook-top-black");
            e.removeClass("vk-top-black");
            f.removeClass("menu-item-facebook-black");
            g.removeClass("menu-item-vk-black");

            $(".menu_item").mouseover(function(){
            $(this).css({"background-color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)"});
            });
            $(".menu_item").mouseout(function(){
            $(this).css({"background-color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)"});
            }); 
      }
        else {
            a.addClass("nav-mobile-black");
            c.addClass("menu-item-black");
            d.addClass("facebook-top-black");
            e.addClass("vk-top-black");
            f.addClass("menu-item-facebook-black");
            g.addClass("menu-item-vk-black");

            $(".menu_item").mouseover(function(){
            $(this).css({"background-color": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)"});    
            });
            $(".menu_item").mouseout(function(){
            $(this).css({"background-color": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)"});
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Please explain "won't work" better. Read these articles to [learn](http://juliepagano.com/blog/2014/05/18/javascript-debugging-for-beginners) [how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging), so you can provide more useful context information (and help yourself).

Comment: It's supported, so the syntax will work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: " i delete the "else if" statement. "  means what you delete entire code after that or replace else if with just if??

Comment: Sometimes with JS issues appear to be one thing, but are a syntax related item with something else... so without seeing your error message, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Your `else` will never be reached and what happens if windowpos and posdown.top are equal? In this case `if` and `else if` will be true. You should rethink your checks/conditions.

Comment: When I don't delete the else if {...}, keeping if {...} and {...}, js just doesn't work. As if there was no js at all in the site.

Comment: @Tom read it again - the first condition is `posup` and the second is `posdown` - the conditions are ok. Also there's nothing wrong with an `if` condition and an `else if` condition both being true - in fact, that's one of the main uses of `else if` - you only want to check the second condition for the cases where the first one isn't true.

Answer (score 0):

You should look in the javascript console. You will most likely see an error like

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
```

My guess is there is no element on the page with `class="head-block"` - which means that `windowpos >= posdown.top` will throw an error, causing your script execution to stop at that point.

It shouldn't affect the other scripts on the page - if it's really killing all javascript, it suggests a compilation error, but there isn't one in what you pasted. Sometimes you can get funny characters in your script that cause this kind of error. If you look into the first possibility and rule it out, try copying the text from your question above back into your script - that should "clean" it if there's anything funny in there.

Either way, your first port of call should always be the javascript console. If my suggestions above don't help, you should look for an error in the console and edit your question to show it.